# your account already has a valid ios distribution certificate (on virtual machine)

Tags: ios, xcode

I was working on a virtual machine, install a new OS yosemite to version 10.10  and old virtual machine deleted. Now I poprobyval unload my new app in App Store and there was such an error:
[image]
I do not want to revok the old certificate - there is a valid application, what should I do?
PS But if I cancel the old certificate - I can create a new certificate, and download the application?

UPDATE i exported account from preferences->Account-> Apple IDs and import it in xcode but still remained the same error

Comment: hi,... Please download old certificates from app store and import it into your keychain. and then try to run the application.

Comment: @AshokLondhe "import it into your keychain" can you tell me more

Comment: it mean download certificate.. and just drag and drop into keychain.

Comment: @AshokLondhe but i have a key and certificate in keychain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are destroyed your private key for certificate when deleted virtual copy. If you not have backup of your Virtual Mashine you have once solution. Just delete old certificate in Dev portal and generate new request with new private key.

How detect Your certificate has private key or not:

[image]

Selected Cert haven't private key, second Cert has.